# What exactly is Django's FileField doing when one clicks the "Browse" button and selects a file? Can I replicate this behavior with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

When rendered, a Django form with a FileField will have a "Browse" button. When clicked, this allows a user to browse through their system, select a file, and hit OK, presumably giving some reference to the file's location, its contents, etc.

This is before the "Submit" button is hit, so nothing is sent to the server—and there are no network requests made, thus there is no actual Python running anywhere. I assume Javascript is doing something because the name of the file pops up, and, somewhere, a reference to the file is stored (and sent to the server when the user clicks "Submit"). The FileField is populated somehow, but I'm not sure how.

What exactly is going on here?

---

I ask because I'd like to replicate this behavior with some AJAX/Javascript alterations. My intended process is this:

1. User makes recording (I use [WebAudioTrack](https://github.com/danielstorey/WebAudioTrack))
2. User clicks "Save," this sends a Blob from the AudioBuffer to some view via AJAX
3. That blob is processed into a WAV file and saved as a temporary file (or something like this).
4. Via some other script, that file is used to populate the form's FileField as if the user had clicked "Browse" and selected a file manually themselves

I'm having problems with Step 4, and it's because I don't know what's actually going on when a FileField is populated (or *any* instance of a user selecting a file for some HTML field).

(Just to emphasize, I'm talking about what happens *before* the user clicks the Submit button.)

Comment: `nothing is sent to the server` I don't think so, have a look at the browsers network tab.

Comment: @JonasW. I did. In my post I stated "... and there are no network requests made." :p

Comment: Then the whole filetree was downloaded when you opened the page

Comment: @JonasW. Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean. If you mean "that's not possible, because then all of the Django/Python modules, etc. would have to be downloaded," then that's just incorrect. Otherwise, what do you mean by "the whole filetree"?

Comment: @JonasW. [Here's a very similar example.](https://jsfiddle.net/63bem4vy/) If you click browse, select a file, and hit OK, *before you hit submit* you can see that there are no network requests made, nothing runs on the server-side, but the filename appears and, presumably, some reference to-eventually-be-sent-to-the-server is stored.

Comment: Thats just an `<input type="file" />` ?! What does that have todo with the server?

Comment: @JonasW. It has *nothing* to do with the server—that's my point! When a user clicks Browse and selects a file, *something* happens to populate that field that is server independent. My question is: What is it that's happening?

Comment: Its the browser that displays your local files? You cannot influence that and you cannot access that feature programmatically.

Comment: Nothing at all is happening, that is the point. This is entirely down to the browser, there is nothing to do with Django here, or JavaScript, or anything. It's just browser behaviour with a file input.